# DSX Desktop on Mac - Example Scala script not working

Tags: data-science-experience, dsx-desktop

After installing DSX desktop on my Mac, any notebook when executed gives this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What Anaconda version do you have installed? During the installation of DSX Desktop, there are different flavors that you can install - Anaconda 2.7, Anaconda 3.5 and then one that has Spark. If you installed just Anaconda 2.7 or Anaconda 3.5, you'll not be able to use notebooks that require Spark. The latest version of DSX Desktop (V1.1.5) only displays Spark sample notebooks if you've the Anaconda with Spark version installed.